# Program only loop through once

Tags: c++, loops

The program reads text from an input file. My output is suppose to read:

```
Level         Score          Stars
----------------------------------
1              3840           **

2              5940           **

3             11560           **

4             18140           **

5             18780           **
```

The stars are suppose to match the level.

The program only displays the first line but the program is written so the loop can display the total output.
For some reason the program loop only runs through the first line of code.

I cant figure out why the program is not looping multiple times. Any advise would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int buildArrays(int A[],int B[],int C[])
{
    int i=0,num;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("candycrush.txt");

    if(inFile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"The candycrush.txt input file did not open"<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    while(inFile)
    {
        inFile>>num;
        A[i]=num;

        inFile>>num;
        B[i]=num;

        inFile>>num;
        C[i]=num;

        i++;
    }
    inFile.close();

    return i;
}

void printArrays( string reportTitle, int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels )
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<reportTitle<<endl;
    cout<<"Levels\tScores\tStars"<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++)
    {
        cout<<levelsArray[i]<<"\t"<<scoresArray[i]<<"\t";
        for(int j=0;j<starsArray[j];j++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void sortArrays( int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels )
{
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<numberOfLevels;j++)
        {
            if(levelsArray[i]<levelsArray[j])
            {
                int temp1=levelsArray[i];
                int temp2=scoresArray[i];
                int temp3=starsArray[i];

                levelsArray[i]=levelsArray[j];
                scoresArray[i]=scoresArray[j];
                starsArray[i]=starsArray[j];

                levelsArray[j]=temp1;
                scoresArray[j]=temp2;
                starsArray[j]=temp3;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    const int MAX=400;
    int levelsArray[MAX];
    int scoresArray[MAX];
    int starsArray[MAX];

    int numberOfLevels=buildArrays(levelsArray,scoresArray,starsArray);

    printArrays( "Candy Crush UNSORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );
    sortArrays( levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels);
    printArrays( "Candy Crush SORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: If you indent your code correctly the problem will be far easier to see

Comment: Can you Show an example of the 'candycrush.txt' file? Also better use `#include <string>` instead of `#include <cstring>` - otherwise it won't compile (tested on VS 2012)

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code works just fine - probably there is either some error in your `candycrush.txt` file or in the file reading. Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int buildArrays(int A[], int B[], int C[]){
    int i=0,num;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      A[i] = 10-i;
      B[i] = 10-i;
      C[i] = 10-i;
    }
    return i;
}

void printArrays( string reportTitle, int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels ){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<reportTitle<<endl;
    cout<<"Levels\tScores\tStars"<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++){
        cout<<levelsArray[i]<<"\t"<<scoresArray[i]<<"\t";
        for(int j=0;j<starsArray[j];j++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void sortArrays( int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels ){
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numberOfLevels;j++){
            if(levelsArray[i]<levelsArray[j]){
                int temp1=levelsArray[i];
                int temp2=scoresArray[i];
                int temp3=starsArray[i];

                levelsArray[i]=levelsArray[j];
                scoresArray[i]=scoresArray[j];
                starsArray[i]=starsArray[j];

                levelsArray[j]=temp1;
                scoresArray[j]=temp2;
                starsArray[j]=temp3;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    const int MAX=400;
    int levelsArray[MAX];
    int scoresArray[MAX];
    int starsArray[MAX];
    int numberOfLevels=buildArrays(levelsArray,scoresArray,starsArray);
    printArrays( "Candy Crush UNSORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );
    sortArrays( levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels);
    printArrays( "Candy Crush SORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );
    system("pause");
}
```

Which will correctly output:

```
Candy Crush UNSORTED Report
Levels  Scores  Stars
---------------------
10      10      **********
9       9       *********
8       8       ********
7       7       *******
6       6       ******
5       5       *****
4       4       ****
3       3       ***
2       2       **
1       1       *

Candy Crush SORTED Report
Levels  Scores  Stars
---------------------
1       1       *
2       2       **
3       3       ***
4       4       ****
5       5       *****
6       6       ******
7       7       *******
8       8       ********
9       9       *********
10      10      **********
```

Also notice a few things:
I removed the `#include <cstring>` and added `#include <string>` - otherwise it won't compile at all (at least on my platform, win32 with VS2012). 
Your `printArrays()` function should Output `starsArray[i]` instead you've written `starsArray[j]` (where j is always 0) - so you're just outputing the stars from the first array Position for all Levels! I fixed this in the provided code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your "candycrush.txt" file contains one or more `*` characters in the 3rd column but you are trying to read that in as an integer. This is of course an error and so the input stream's error state is set. Subsequent reads from this stream will fail while it's in this state.

Fixing this is pretty straightforward -- just read the last column in as a full string. This will also simplify your `printArrays` since you don't have to count the `*` anymore; just print it out as is.

Here's your `buildArrays` fixed up a bit with an actual size so it doesn't overrun:

```
template <size_t maxsize>
int buildArrays(istream &is, int (&A)[maxsize], 
                             int (&B)[maxsize], 
                             std::string (&C)[maxsize])
{
  assert(is);

  size_t i;
  for(i = 0; i < maxsize && is; ++i)
  {
    is >> A[i] >> B[i] >> C[i];
  }

  return i;
}
```

Your main opens the input file and just passes the `ifstream` into `buildArrays`:

```
int main()
{
  const int MAX = 400;
  int levelsArray[MAX];
  int scoresArray[MAX];
  string starsArray[MAX];

  ifstream infile("candycrush.txt");
  int numberOfLevels = buildArrays(infile, levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray);
  // and other stuff
  // ...
}
```