# Program is not displaying output correctly

Tags: c++, loops

My program is supposed to display information from a text file.
The text file is here http://pastebin.com/qB6nX2x4

I can't find the problem in my program. I think it has to deal with the looping but I'm not sure. My program runs correctly but only displays the first line of text.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int buildArrays(int A[],int B[],int C[])
{

    int i=0,num;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("candycrush.txt");

    if(inFile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"The candycrush.txt input file did not open"<<endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(inFile)
    {
        inFile>>num;
        A[i]=num;

        inFile>>num;
        B[i]=num;

        inFile>>num;
        C[i]=num;

        i++;
    }
    inFile.close();

    return i;
}

void printArrays( string reportTitle, int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels )
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<reportTitle<<endl;
    cout<<"Levels\tScores\tStars"<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++)
    {
        cout<<levelsArray[i]<<"\t"<<scoresArray[i]<<"\t";

        for(int j=0;j<starsArray[j];j++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}


void sortArrays( int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels )
{
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<numberOfLevels;j++)
        {
            if(levelsArray[i]<levelsArray[j])
            {
                int temp1=levelsArray[i];
                int temp2=scoresArray[i];
                int temp3=starsArray[i];

                levelsArray[i]=levelsArray[j];
                scoresArray[i]=scoresArray[j];
                starsArray[i]=starsArray[j];

                levelsArray[j]=temp1;
                scoresArray[j]=temp2;
                starsArray[j]=temp3;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    const int MAX=400;
    int levelsArray[MAX];
    int scoresArray[MAX];
    int starsArray[MAX];

    int numberOfLevels=buildArrays(levelsArray,scoresArray,starsArray);

    printArrays( "Candy Crush UNSORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );
    sortArrays( levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels);
    printArrays( "Candy Crush SORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: "My program runs correctly" hm, if it produces an incorrect output, then this statement is obviously not true (do you mean it runs through without crashing?). please rather describe what it *should* do...

Comment: Isn't this the same question as your other question [Program only loop through once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902164/program-only-loop-through-once)?

Comment: Problem seems fairly clear. Your file contains entries like this `***` but you are trying to read that as if it was a number `inFile>>num; C[i]=num;` It should be obvious that won't work.

Comment: The program should run the output file. It only runs the first line of code.

Comment: In file represents the text. The program is reading output from the input file.

Comment: The only Thing that Looks like C++ in your code are the includes. Everything else Looks like C: three Arrays instead of one struct/class, fixed size Arrays instead of vector, own sort instead of std::sort. And what is this system("pause") at the end? This is really ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I didn't make myself clear in my comment.

Your program is failing because you try to read asterisks as if they were numbers. The first line of your input contains asterisks which you try to read as if it was a number. Obviously this fails and at this point *all further reading stops*. This is why you only see one line of output.

You need to either change your code to read asterisks, or change your asterisks to real numbers.

Remember computers do precisely what you tell them. You tell the computer to read a integer, then an integer is what the computer expects, not a string of asterisks representing an integer.

BTW sorry to say this but your sort code is incorrect as well. You'll see this when you've fixed the input code.